# C, last element of the list pointing on nothing

Tags: c, list, pointers, recursion, linked-list

I have a question: the following function copies the list of pointers linked list in a second one if they are equal.
FX
list1 = 1 2 3 3 5 6 7 7 7

the result after the call will be:

list2 = 3 7

```
node *seqdup(node *lis)
{
    if(lis == NULL)
        return NULL;
    else if (lis->next != NULL)
        {
            if(lis->data == lis->next->data)
                {
                    node *p;
                    p = newnode();
                    p->data = lis->next->data;
                    p->next = seqdup(lis->next);
                    return p;
                }
            else
                return seqdup(lis->next);
        }
}
```

I know it's a useless function, it was for a school exam.

The problem with it is:
I made it for a school assignment, and got a total of 2 points out of the 10 for the exercise for not including a condition such as "if (lis->next == NULL) return NULL;"
due to the fact that when reading the last last node of the list, the function is gonna do nothing: fx if the lis is 1 1 3 4

for the first node, lis->next != NULL he finds 1 == 1` so copies in lis 2
for the second, lis->next != NULL, and 1 != 3, so rec call, but no copy
the third one however, since 3 != 4, it does nothing

problem is, thaat as long as I assign lis->next after the recursive call, last copied node of the second list is basically gonna point on a function that does nothing.

Obviously my teacher is right at being severe about the problem, as there are a lot of easy ways to fix it. My problem however is: WHY DOES IT WORK ANYWAY?

Tried to write it down and compile it and works like a charm :/

Comment: To clarify: you're asking "How come my function returns `NULL` when it goes through a code path that doesn't explicitly `return`?"

Comment: Something like that yes.
After running that function, I went through the returned list with a print function (print the data field as long as lis != NULL) and everything worked perfectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it worked for you, that just means you got lucky, and the eax register happened to be zero when the condition fell through. So it was as if you had a `return NULL` at the end of the function.

When I tested this in my compiler, that wasn't the case, and the code didn't work. For me, the eax register held the value of *lis*, so it was as if you had `return lis` at the end of the function. That just produced a list that looped forever.

Comment: I see: actually that's why I thought, it's basically a matter of luck.
At the same time however it's quite weird as I tried to run the function for 150.000 times (called it with another fuction) and had no issues with it.

Btw: is I'm saying something dumb forgive me, I'm new to programming in general (started university this year and coming from a type of school where coding isnt a subject). 
I do however know the issue is typical of C, declaring a variable doesn't set it to anything but unknown (or atleast that's how they explained it). Just like declaring int a; and printing it.

Comment: @Eloh666 The issue of whether it's going to work or not is mostly decided at compile time, not run time. If the compiler produces assembly code that has the eax register set to zero at that point in the function, it is always going to work. If it produces code that has the eax register set to something else, it's almost always going to fail. Running it multiple times is unlikely to change anything. Using a different compiler, or slightly changing the code, is what will produce different results.

Comment: I see, didn't really thought of that but it does make perfect sense.

Thanks!

Comment: A beautiful example of why you should never depend on undefined behaviour.  It leads you to false conclusions.

Comment: I know that, really. The problem was that knowing that it wasn't supposed to work, it was still working and it got me wondering. At first I did however think it was an optimization of the compiler, however the registry choice explanation makes perfect sense.